# Taking csv file columns as arguments

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, input

I have 3 columns in csv file that I want to use as arguments for python functions calculating min, max, mean.
I only want to def 3 functions and not one for each one.

What do i take as arguments?

I have tried many different things and the picture below is my most clever(im new to this) solution

[image]

Comment: Using pictures is not recommended, please paste Your code.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). -  [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Do you want to calculate those statistics for each row or for each column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting the max, min or std from a DF for a particular column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740018/extracting-the-max-min-or-std-from-a-df-for-a-particular-column-in-pandas) - valid for rows also.

Answer (score 0):

For your functions, you need to pass a separate variable for each argument your function calls for. If you want to create a new column in the dataframe that contains the max for the three columns "X", "Y", "Z", you would use apply and lambda to iterate through each row, send each entry from the three columns to the function, and put the output of the function in the new column. Using your example, it would look like:

```
df['Max'] = df.apply(lambda x: max_value(x['X'],x['Y'], x['Z']), axis=1)
```

This will create a new column in the dataframe with the header "Max", and the max of the "X", "Y", and "Z" columns for each row will be output there. [Apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) applies the function max_value to each row in the dataframe, and the three arguments are sent to the function from the X,Y, and Z columns.

Your function would then need to look something like:

```
def max_value(X, Y, Z):
    max_val = max(X, Y, Z)
    return max_val
```

The functions takes the three arguments: X, Y, Z, which are passed by the apply function, which takes each of the arguments from the associated column in each row.

Let me know if I didn't understand the question.

Edit:

Depending on how the dataset loads from the csv, you may need to reset the index before calling the function:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, you understanded it correctly. Do you know why it say  ('X', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: added an edit, the problem is how your table df is arranged. Also make sure you include axis=1 in the apply function. If resetting doesn't work and you can print the df and post to your question that may help answer the question.